# Mongo Shell Query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, java-8

Is there any easy way of firing Mongo query in Java??

```
db.Test.aggregate(
    [
    {
        '$match':
        {
        'o': { '$gt': [] }
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
        'uid': 1,
        'o': 1
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
        '_id': 0,
        'uid': 1,
        o: {
            $filter: {
            input: "$o",
            as: "item",
            cond: {
                $and: [
                {
                    $lt: [ "$$item.ad", 0 ]
                },
                {
                    $lt: [ "$$item.at", 0 ]
                }
                ]
            }
            }
        }
        }
    },
    {
        '$match': {
        'o': { '$gt': []}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
        uid: 1,
        "mids": "$o.mid"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$mids"
    },
    {
        $group: {
        _id: {
            uid: "$uid",
            mid: "$mids"
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
        _id: 0,
        uid: "$_id.uid",
        mid: "$_id.mid",
        count: 1
        }
    }
    ]
);
```

Is http://jongo.org serve the purpose for complex queries?

Comment: I did not know jongo until now but it seems to make the querying in java a lot more palatable by using the JSON style query language.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the Java driver's `Document.parse()` method. You can supply a JSON string to the method (following MongoDB's [extended JSON formatting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)), and it will return a parsed BSON document for you.

Please see http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html#parse-java.lang.String- for the method's documentation.